# Problem with column names in a function in R when running linear discriminant analysis (lda)

Tags: r, function, parsing, linear-discriminant

This is my dataset of example, where column `D` is the factor one.

```
df <- data.frame(A=1:10, B=2:11, C=3:12, D="A")
df[6:10, 4] <- "B"
```

When I run a `lda`, it works nice:

```
model <- lda(D ~  B + C, data = df)

print(model)

Call:
lda(D ~ B + C, data = df)

Prior probabilities of groups:
  A   B 
0.5 0.5 

Group means:
  B  C
A 4  5
B 9 10

Coefficients of linear discriminants:
        LD1
B 0.3162278
C 0.3162278
```

However, when I try to replicate this into a function, I get stucked.

```
fun1 <- function(x, column){
  model <- lda(column ~  B + C, data = x)
  print(model)
}
```

I tried several options:

- With quotes -> `fun1(df, "D")`
- Without quotes -> `fun1(df, D)`

In both cases I get errors that are displayed below:

```
# fun1(df, "D")
Error in model.frame.default(formula = column ~ B + C, data = x) : 
variable lengths differ (found for 'B')

# fun1(df, D)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = column ~ B + C, data = x) : 
object is not a matrix
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`column` in your model formula is treated as a variable name that is expected in the supplied data and it will not be evaluated to whatever you set the `column` variable to (e.g. `'D'`). You have to explicitly build the formula so that this evaluation is performed, e.g. using `reformulate`:

```r
fun1 <- function(x, column){
  form <- reformulate(c('B', 'C'), column)
  model <- lda(form, data = x)
  print(model)
}

fun1(df, 'D')
```